# How to wait until evaluate step done in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

Let's say I have this script:

```
var me = null;

casper
    .start()
    .then(function(){
        me = this.evaluate(someFunction);
    })
    .wait(5000) //this what i doing until now
    .then(nextFunction)

casper.run()
```

I need calculate `me` from evaluate then execute `me` in nextFunction.

The problem is, I don't know exactly when the evaluate finish. To fix this I usually use wait() with certain seconds.

I don't like this, because I can't execute `nextFunction` ASAP. In jQuery I can use callback/promise to get rid of this, but how to do this on casperJS?

I try this, but got no luck,

```
var me = null;

casper
    .start()
    .then(myEval)
    .wait(5000) //this what i doing until now
    .then(nextFunction)

casper.run()

function myEval(){
    me = this.evaluate(someFunction);
    if(me==null) this.wait(2000, myEval);
}
```

So I keep adding ugly wait() in my script since I learn casperjs until now.

### Update

Result from suggested answer:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var me = 'bar';

function timeoutFunction(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        return 'foo';
    },5000);
}

function loopFunction(i){
    var a = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=1000;i++){
        a=i;
    }
    return a;
}

function nextFunction(i){
    this.echo(i);
}

casper
    .start('http://casperjs.org/')
    .then(function(){
            me = this.evaluate(timeoutFunction);
            return me;
    }).then(function() {
        this.echo(me); //null instead foo or bar
        me = this.evaluate(loopFunction);
        return me
    }).then(function() {
        this.echo(me);//1000 => correct
        nextFunction(me); //undefined is not function. idk why 
    });
casper.run();
```

Comment: You could just call `nextFunction`inside the `then` function after setting the `me` value. Does this work for you?

Comment: @LuizCarlos thats not work. i try it several times. btw, can you give me example code, you no need to try that, i will try for you. because maybe i just missundersood what do you mean

Comment: Helpful feedback: I downvoted for the lack of spelling and case in this post. Please use the ordinary case rules for English, and spell-check everything, prior to posting.

Comment: (The odd mistake is fine, of course, but getting it wrong deliberately for "aesthetic" reasons is not.)

Comment: i upvote cz u give the reason. thats very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Promises chaining, like this:

```
casper
.start()
.then(function(){
    me = this.evaluate(someFunction);
    return me;
}).then(function(me) {
  // me is the resolved value of the previous then(...) block
  console.log(me);
  nextFunction(me);
  });
```

Another generic example can be found [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

Comment: me in second function become casper object: `{"contentType":"text/html; charset=utf-8","headers":[{"name":"Server","value":"GitHub.com"}, too long to post here`

Comment: js in casperjs is similar but different according to js in browser

Comment: Could you elaborate what you're trying to achieve? JavaScript promises work the same way, regardless of the framework/library your using. You don't need to wait by setting a timeout. If you chain these promises, you'll have the result of the first block as soon as it's been calculated.